# plot() does not show all diagnostic plots for lme/lmer

Tags: r, plot

When using the lme/lmer function, I cannot get R to display all 4 diagnostic plots (res vs fit, normal-QQ, scale-location, res vs leverage) with par(mfrow=c(2,2)) and plot().
I just get the res vs fit plot and nothing else.
I have no problem when using the lm function.
Does anybody know how to do this?

```r
library(lme4)
m0<-lmer(hematology~Treatment*day+Gender+(1|ID),data=long,na.action=na.omit,REML=FALSE)
par(mfrow=c(2,2))
plot(m0)
```

Answer (score 8):

**tl;dr** `?plot.merMod` explains in quite a bit of detail how the plotting methods work for fits produced by `[g]lmer` ...

You can get at least the first three plots corresponding to `plot.lm` fairly easily:

### fitted vs residual with smooth line added

```
plot(lmer_model, type=c("p","smooth"), col.line=1)
```

(it's harder to get the smooth and the zero line drawn in different colours)

### scale-location plot

```
plot(lmer_model,
     sqrt(abs(resid(.)))~fitted(.),
     type=c("p","smooth"), col.line=1)
```

### Q-Q plot

```
lattice::qqmath(lmer_model)
```

### residuals vs leverage

```
plot(fm1, rstudent(.) ~ hatvalues(.))
```

(the Cook's distances can be computed via `cooks.distance()` but superimposing the contours of CD={0.5,1} isn't so easy ...)

#### historical note

The design and implementation of `lme4` diagnostic plot methods differ from `plot.lm`, which is the canonical example in base R.  Why? I don't know for sure, but this approach is derived from the `nlme` package, which predates R; the earliest version I could find is [this page from the Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/19980110014044/http://franz.stat.wisc.edu/pub/NLME/) (1998), which links to a [copy of the user's guide](https://web.archive.org/web/19980419040438/http://franz.stat.wisc.edu/pub/NLME/U_Guide.ps) for version 1.2, dated February 1995; that's three months before the first source-code release of R (via ftp) in [June 1995](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/html/interface98-paper/paper_2.html).

- it uses `lattice` (derived from Trellis™ graphics) rather than base-R graphics
- although it doesn't automatically construct e.g. scale-location plots, it is more flexible. You can use formulas to show fitted or residual values vs parameters, facet, etc., e.g. `plot(fm1,residuals(.)~Days|Subject)`
- there are separate commands for plotting residuals etc. (`plot`) and Q-Q plots (`qqnorm` in `nlme`, `qqmath` in `lme4`)

Comment: Thank you. This was really helpful

Answer (score 5):

As long as we're adding answers, the [performance](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/performance/index.html) package is now available:

```r
library(lme4)
library(performance)
fm1 <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (Days|Subject), sleepstudy)
check_model(fm1)
```

[image]

Comment: WOW! This is an even better output!

Answer (score 3):

I know that this is a 2-year-old question, but I was having the same issue (September/2022) and then I found [Panel of Diagnostic Residual Plots](https://goodekat.github.io/ggResidpanel/reference/resid_panel.html) and [redres](https://goodekat.github.io/redres/)

```
resid_panel(mod1, smoother = TRUE, qqbands = TRUE)
```

which shows:

[image: these plots]

Answer (score 1):

In R, `plot` is a generic function. This means that when you call `plot`, R examines the class of the object you have passed to the first argument and chooses the plotting method according to this class.

Let's take an example. Suppose I use the `lm` function to create a model. The resulting model object will have class `"lm"`:

```r
lm_model <- lm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width, data = iris)
class(lm_model)
#> [1] "lm"
```

That means that when I call `plot(lm_model)`, R will see that I am calling `plot` on an object of class `lm`. Instead of trying to construct a basic xy plot as it would if I did `plot(1:10)`, R now knows to call a plotting method that has been specifically written to plot objects of type `"lm"`. In this case, it will dispatch the method `stats:::plot.lm`, which is a long function that takes the `"lm"` object and creates the 4 diagnostic plots.

Now let's see what we get when we create a model with `lmer`:

```r
library(lme4)
lmer_model <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (Days | Subject), sleepstudy)
class(lmer_model)
#> [1] "lmerMod"
#> attr(,"package")
#> [1] "lme4"
```

Our model is an object of type `"lmerMod"`. When we call `plot` on this object, R looks up the correct method to plot an object of this class. Since it has a completely different structure from an object of class `"lm"`, it wouldn't make sense to plot it with `plot.lm`, so the authors who created the `lme4` package had to decide what the best way to plot an object of class `"lmerMod"` was. They wrote the method `lme4:::plot.merMod`, which draws the single plot you see when you call `plot` on your model.

Why is this? That's one for the authors to answer, but it seems the main reason is that they wanted a plot method that would cover GLMM, LMM and REML models. The diagnostic plots for `lm` don't make sense for all of these model types.

So the short answer is that there is no problem to "solve" as such; this is just not how `"lmerMod"` objects are plotted. If you have specific concerns about some aspects of your fit that can be answered by these diagnostic plots, you should examine these individually.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I really appreciate it :) !

Comment: Why? Is probably less principled than you suggest.  It would have been possible to produce similar plots to `plot.lm` ...

Comment: @BenBolker As I said, that's one for the authors to answer. If only one of them could comment about that on this thread...

Comment: @BenBolker perhaps a separate method for `plot.lmerMod` ? My guess was that you'd figured you'd get some ugly / unhelpful QQ plots with certain GLMMs, so you stuck to a residuals-only plot across the piece, but that might be completely wrong. I'd be interested to know, since I'd wondered about this in passing myself a few years ago.